# Elastic search Range Aggregation query on minimum valued nested field

Tags: elasticsearch

I am looking for an aggregation query on "price" field which is in a nested field.

The mapping of each document is

```
"Item": {
  "id": {
    "type": "integer"
  }
  "products":{
    "properties": {
       "price": {
        "type": "double"
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "string"
      }
   }
}
```

Let's say that I have 3 documents,

```
Item1:
{
  "id:1,
  "products":[
      {"name":"aa", "price":100.0}
      {"name":"bb", "price":200.0}
      {"name":"cc", "price":300.0}
  ]
}

Item2:
{
  "id:2,
  "products":[
      {"name":"dd", "price":400.0}
      {"name":"ee", "price":300.0}
  ]
}

Item3:
{
  "id:3,
  "products":[
      {"name":"ff", "price":150.0}
      {"name":"gg", "price":50.0}
      {"name":"ff", "price":250.0}
  ]
}
```

I need a range aggregation query which aggregates on minimum priced product of each item.

```
"aggregations" : {
     "nested_aggs" : {
        "nested" : {
        "path" : "products"
      },
     "aggregations" : {
          "price_range" : {
             "range" : {
                "field" : "products.price",
                "ranges" : [
                   {
                    "to" : 200.0
                   },
                   {
                    "from" : 200.0,
                    "to" : 400.0
                   }
                 ],
                 "keyed" : false
                }
              }
            }
        }
    }





Expected output: 0-200: 2 (Item1 & item3)
               200-400: 1 (Item2),
```

I couldn't specify the aggregate filter condition to consider the nested object with minimum price

Any help is greatly appreciated.